# How can I get hibernate to persist a one-to-many sub-subclass of a MappedSuperclass without altering the parent classes?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, polymorphism

I have an abstract `@MappedSuperclass`, `Vehicle`, and a concrete implementation `Car`.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Vehicle { ... }

@Entity
@Table(schema = "Dealer", name = "Cars")
public class Car {
    ...
    // you can have any color you like, as long as it's black...
    private final String color = "Black";  

    public String getColor() { return "Black"; }
}
```

However, those implementations are not under my control so I can not change `Vehicle` or `Car`, and I can not change the database either.  Assume that there's a read-only list of `Car` in the dealer's schema to which I have access.  Of course, there are many other methods in `Car` too, as well as other `Vehicles`, `Bike`, `Skateboard`, etc.

I run a paint shop, so I provide `PaintedCar`, which overrides `getColor()`.  In all other ways, this class is identical to `Car`:

```
public class PaintedCar extends Car {
    ...
    private String customColor;

    @Override
    public String getColor() { return customColor; }

}
```

The same `Car` can be painted multiple times, or different instances of `Car` can be painted differently by different owners, so there's a possibility for one `Car` to many `PaintedCar`s.

Theoretically, I should be able to store all the information I need to represent a `PaintedCar` in a table with fields:

```
int paintedCarId;
int carId;  /* FK to Car */
varchar color;
```

Note that `PaintedCar` must be an instance of `Car`, not just an implementation of `Vehicle`.  However, I can't quite figure out how to get Hibernate to persist this relationship.  What's the trick?

Comment: If you have a one-to-many association between Car and PaintedCar, then clearly PaintedCar is not a Car, and should be named something else, like CarPainting for example: a car has many CarPaintings. You have a *has* association, and not a *is-a* association, so inheritance is not the right approach.

Comment: Thanks. This is a contrived example, simpler than my real problem.  However I need an object which is a Car, so that I can pass it to Freeway.addVehicle(Car c), which will call Car.drive().  I *also* need to override Car.getColor() to return some other color than Black.  I'm adding a property to an existing object, but it's still the same object.  I can take one Car instance (with carId=1), wrap in in PaintedCar to paint it blue (paintedCarId=1), asme for red(paintedCarId=2). I can pass both to Freeway.addVehicle(), and have two Cars on the road.  All works from Java but not hibernate.